# How to stick word in input when user type something

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to float a label , it working fine . When user focus on input and type something the label text is stick above when user click on next field the input text is disappear and label text place in input . I need to check if someone type I want to stick float label words above . I will attach fiddle link please check . Help will be really appreciated .

Thanks

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/b7dc5ojt/23/)

```
  .newForm {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.newForm input {
  width: "100%";
  padding: 10px;
}

.newForm input:focus + label {
  color: #0f73ee;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  top: -10px;
}

.newForm input:focus + label:after {
  content: ":";
}

.newForm input:not(:focus) {
  content: ":";
}

.newForm label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 25px;
  color: #777;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is that your Label is acting as a placeholder and is obviously floating back to its position.

Instead of using the Label as Placeholder and Float it i recommend you do the following:

Put the Label where it shoudl be while the user Types (above the Field) and use CSS (visibility or opacity) to hide it.

As Placeholder use the correct placeholder as its supposed to be:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name"/>
```

And once the User clicks into the field just change the Visibiltiy / Opacity of your label so it is visible. Why use an Element as Placeholder when HTML offers you one?

Comment: If you need help or an example i can provide you with the Code for my solution, i just prefer to give the explanation so you can fix it yourself first :)

Comment: Thank you for answer , could you please edit fiddle ?

Comment: or give any example

Comment: Actually I want to keep label text when user type something or text in input . Now , when I move to next field it hide the label text

Comment: you want the label to stay after the user typed something in?

Answer (score 1):

add attribute required in the input field and add this line of code is css

input:valid + label{
top : -10px
}

```css
.content {
  margin-left:50px;
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
}

.newForm {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.newForm input {
  width: "100%";
  padding: 10px;
}

.newForm input:focus + label {
  color: #0f73ee;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  top: -10px;
}

.newForm input:focus + label:after {
  content: ":";
}

.newForm input:not(:focus) {
  content: ":";
}

.newForm label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 25px;
  color: #777;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
input:valid + label{
  top : -10px;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>New title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="newForm">
        <input
                class="form-control input-box focusText"
                id="first" required
        />
        <label for="first">First Name</label>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```